# The third transform execute with previous executor

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a doubt about the usage of multiple Scheduler strategies in the same method.

```java
Function<Object, Flux<String>> fetchGreekGods = obj -> {

    return Flux.just(this.config.getApiMap().get(GREEK))
            .publishOn(Schedulers.immediate())
            .map(toURL)
            .map(fetch)
            .flatMap(serializeFlux)
            .log();
};

Function<Flux<String>, Flux<Tuple2<String, Integer>>> fetchWikipediaGodInfo = god -> {

    return Flux.from(god)
            .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())
            .map(str -> {
                return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(str, generateWikiAddress
                        .andThen(toURL)
                        .andThen(fetch)
                        .andThen(String::length)
                        .apply(str));
            })
            .log();
};

Function<Flux<Tuple2<String, Integer>>, Flux<String>> max = godInfo -> {

    return Flux.from(godInfo)
            .publishOn(Schedulers.immediate())
            .sort(Comparator.comparing(Tuple2::_2))
            .takeLast(1)
            .map(t -> t._1)
            .log();
};

public Mono<String> reactorSolution() {

        return Flux.empty()
            .transform(fetchGreekGods)
            .transform(fetchWikipediaGodInfo)
            .transform(max)
            .next();
}
```

Why if I define different Schedulers per transform, in the last one, in the execution of Max, in the logs, I observe the strategy from the previous one: `fetchWikipediaGodInfo`

In the logic, I would like that for `max`, the code use main thread but currently, I observe the previous one.

```
2019-09-22 18:08:30 [elastic-2] INFO  reactor.Flux.MapFuseable.3 - | onNext(Apollo)
2019-09-22 18:08:30 [elastic-2] INFO  reactor.Flux.MapFuseable.3 - | cancel()
2019-09-22 18:08:30 [elastic-2] INFO  reactor.Flux.MapFuseable.3 - | onComplete()
```

In theory, the third transform, should run in main thread, but currently the method is running in elastic but it is incorrect because I defined explicitly to run in main thread.

How to fix it?

Many thanks in advance

Juan Antonio

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation about [Schedulers](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers)

> The Schedulers class has static methods that give access to the
>   following execution contexts:
>
> - The current thread (Schedulers.immediate()).

Current thread does not have to be the main thread it can very well be the last thread. And the transform before is using elastic.

Comment: Oki, so my question is how to execute the last transform in the main thread. The first one: Main, the second: Elastic, the third one: main

Comment: You need to understand that there is no "main thread" in reactive. Only different threadpools. When you are telling it to use `elastic()` you are basically telling it to use another scheduler and use the elastic function saying that the application can spawn as many threads needed on that scheduler.

Comment: if you want it to use the default `ForkJoinPool` you just remove the scheduling then it will assign that process to use the default pool.